# how to implement constraints on a web application workflow based on rules

Tags: java, web-applications, workflow, validationrules

We have the following problem in our web application.
There is a workflow for creating an order on the application :

- entering informations about the customer (one web form)
- entering informations about the device (another web form)

and some constraints on each form in order to advance to the next step :

- the customer has a series of attributes (first name, last name, street, telephone number) which need to be specified
- when the customer wants to be notified by sms then a valid mobile phone number needs to be introduced
- for the device (for a which a payment type (Card/Cash/Cheque) retrieved dy there is a certain amount of money to be accepted by the customer in order to create the order

Currently these constraints are implemented directly in the source code of the application, and this is making the application harder to maintain (some of the rules change from a version of the application to the next).

What would be a good approach to externalize these checks from the code when creating the order?

A rule-engine like Drools could be a good solution, but I'd like to give the possibility to the administrator of the site, via a visual editor to define the validation rules.
Can anybody recommend me a solution which exists already for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

to some extent spring-webflow can help you. otherwise there are various workflow/bpm kind of solutions available (i had worked on Savvion BPM once), then I think jboss drools is there.

Comment: I am having a look on Drools Expert. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate process for validating information from the user. we have created a servlet that all request come through (You could use JSP's if you wanted). When a request comes in we can get the request parameters and pass them to the validation classes along with what type of form the user filled out. The validation classes would do the required validation and then pass back true or false along with the names of any fields that failed.

When the servlet starts up it would go to a database or XML file and retrieve the required fields for each form and store it in it's cache. The fields in the database or XML file would have the same name as the fields in the HTML form. If you wanted to add/remove a field that is required you would just need to add/remove the field in the HTML form and add/remove the field from the database or XML file. No code changes would be needed. Since the validation data is stored in cache the database or XML file would only be read once when the server is started. If performance is not an issue you could read from the database or XML file every time.

You could also validate that the data was valid (ex. last name has valid characters) by also storing regular expressions along with the form field names. This way you could change how a field is validated by just changing the expression in the database or XML file. No code changes no major retesting.

Comment: There are rules to be applied dynamically - when the user wants to be notified by sms then the mobile phone needs to be a valid number, otherwise not. There's also the case when having a specific payment type for the order (which is configured in the database/property file) then a certain checkbox (accept amount of money to be payed). Only a simple XML file would not fit complex/dynamic rules.

Comment: In the case of payment type. You could store the name of the field for payment type in the database. Then in the database tie the payment type field to the check box along with what values of the payment type require validation of the check box. This is the type of problem I would need to have an over all picture of the process. I could not give you a good design without fully understanding the process. Sorry